# What happens if a manual Apex trigger is sending events to an offline endpoint?

Tags: apex, trigger, streaming-api

Say that I create an apex trigger on the `Account` or `AccountChangeEvent` `sObject` and this trigger acts in a way that it:

1. Gets the event by calling `Trigger.new`
2. Converts the event to serialized JSON
3. Sends the event to a HTTP endpoint by calling a `post` method from a HTTP Callout class

What if the actual endpoint is offline at the time? Does the event get lost? Will the trigger re-execute or can I create a "retry until successful" mechanism? Does this act the same or differently between apex triggers created with `Account` or `AccountChangeEvent`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on your own, so to speak, to build any desired retry functionality. It is not built in to the platform. Your code will likely receive a `CalloutException`, depending on exactly what is wrong at the remote end.

It's important to note that you can't make synchronous callouts from Apex triggers. You'll have to move the actual callout into an asynchronous context, such as a Queueable. Queueables offer capabilities that make retry structures feasible, including chaining into another Queueable to retry failed callouts, or persisting the operation state into an sObject that can be retried against until it succeeds.

The other clear option, since you mention `AccountChangeEvent`, is to drop the Apex layer entirely. Your remote system can subscribe to Change Data Capture events on the sObjects in which you are interested, and utilize the built-in replay feature in CDC to capture events that were to be delivered during the period when the remote system was down.